# Creating teigger error in mysql 5.59

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, count

everyone.
I want to count a id's count in A(a table) when after inserting a record,my sql is bleow:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_data_count
AFTER
INSERT
ON A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     SELECT @data_count:=COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

As we see, I had make some mistakes(^_^).

My mysql version info: Ver 14.14 Ditrib 5.5.9,for Win64(X86).The error message is:

```
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL    server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
---------------------------------------------------

Query : end

Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
```

At last, thanks everyone.

Comment: what do you want to do with the result? i think trigger will not help you here.

Comment: I want to do somethings like this:if data_count == 0 then (insert data to B);elseif data_count > 1 then (insert data to C).the codes in brackets are pseudo-code.

Comment: finish by a '/' instead of a ';'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do an select, update, delete on the same table from which the trigger fired.

From the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9):

```
B.5.9: Can triggers access tables?

A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.
```

Comment: It also has a mistake:Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000
---------------------------------------------------
Query : END
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: Well I'm used to program in an Oracle DB. But when using NEW and OLD in triggers you can only use NEW when creating a trigger which acts BEFORE an insert, update, ... Try to replace NEW by OLD

Comment: en,in mysql, the OLD.xxx means before the insert,update,.. ^_^

Comment: Did you give it a try? :P Otherwise I don't really see anything wrong. Have you declared the variable @data_count?

Comment: yes, before asking the question,I have tried everything I can do.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I know it. Normally you can't do a select on the same table when there is occurring a trigger on it. You can do a select on another table but not on the table where the trigger is happening.

Comment: Yeah,Maybe you are right,Could give me the link of "can't do a select on the same table when there is occurring a trigger on it".^_^.In any way, thanks a lot.

Comment: Here ya go :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9. I'll modify my anwser

Comment: Ok,thanks a lot,I will set your anwser as accepted anwser after you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use delimiters in your `CREATE TRIGGER` query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_data_count AFTER INSERT ON A
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SELECT @data_count:=COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE id = NEW.id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```